# Express Static Middleware will not be created

Tags: javascript, express, remix.run

I want to pack my Remix.run app on an express server so that I can host it. The problem is that express does not create the static middlewares and I get errors because the remix app needs them.

I have already looked but have not yet found a solution that applies to my problem. I have already checked the ports and looked at which routes it creates.

express:

```js
import { createRequestHandler } from "@remix-run/express";
import express from "express";

// notice that the result of `remix build` is "just a module"
import * as build from "./build/index.js";
import { broadcastDevReady } from "@remix-run/node";

const app = express();
app.use("/", express.static("public"));

// and your app is "just a request handler"
app.all("*", createRequestHandler({ build }));

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("App listening on http://localhost:8000");

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    broadcastDevReady(build);
  }
});

const routes = [];
app._router.stack.forEach((middleware) => {
  if (middleware.route) {
    // Routen, die direkt in der App definiert sind
    routes.push(middleware.route.path);
  } else if (middleware.name === 'router') {
    // Routen, die durch einen Router erstellt wurden
    middleware.handle.stack.forEach((handler) => {
      if (handler.route) {
        routes.push(handler.route.path);
      }
    });
  }
});

// Ausgabe der gefundenen Routen
console.log('Verfügbare Routen:', routes);
```

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGKld.png)

I would like all files from the public folder and build folder to be available as middleware.

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working and perhaps a solution?